# Using With Statement instead of creating Object Reference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know that it is good to have meaningful variable names, but in a situation where an object is used briefly than throw it away it seems reasonable to just wrap it in a With statement.

Consider the an example situation of looping through a Gridview's rows finding a control and updating it.

```
For Each gvr as GridViewRow in gvExample.Rows 
    Dim txtExample as Textbox
    txtExample = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("txtExample"),Textbox)
    txtExample.Text = "hi"
    txtExample.Enabled = False
    '... more with same object
next
```

This could be written using With without making a local variable:

```
For each gvr as GridViewRow in gvExample.Rows
    With DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("txtExample"),Textbox)
        .Text = "hi"
        .Enabled = False
    '... more with same object
    End With
next
```

Obviously, there's also the compromise of:

```
For Each gvr as GridViewRow in gvExample.Rows 
   Dim txtExample as Textbox
   txtExample = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("txtExample"),Textbox)
   With txtExample
      .Text = "hi"
      .Enabled = False
      '... more with same object
   End With
next
```

For the sake argument, lets assume that I know `gvr.FindControl("txtExample")` will always return a Textbox.

I have a preference for the 2nd method. Are there reasons I would want to avoid using `With` this way? Is either way or another you provide generally better? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I choose none of the above.

As much as single-letter variables are maligned, that would still provide at least as much context as the the `With` keyword, and so should be considered an improvement. In practice I'd likely go with a two or three letter mnemonic here. Add a quick Select() linq projection and the result is this:

```
Dim boxes = gvExample.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow).Select(Function(gvr) gvr.FindControl("txtExample"))
For Each e as TextBox in boxes

    e.Text = "hi"
    e.Enabled = False
    '... more with same object
Next
```

No need for the DirectCast() operator: the `As TextBox` clause took care of it. The new `Option Infer` means that `Dim` line with no type is still type safe.

Comment: Finally attempted to implement this and receive error: `'select' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'.`

Comment: Apparently, the correct syntax is `gvExample.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow).Select ...` unless there's some trick I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Because the second and third methods compile to essentially the same IL, the difference is probably only one of convenience: in Visual Studio 2010, the third method (but not the second) lets you inspect `txtExample`, `.Text`, and `.Enabled` with the debugger by simply hovering over those identifiers with the mouse.